# Notepad++ - Custom font style?

Tags: html, notepad++

How can I use a custom font on Notepad++? 
For example: I have an HTML document with couple of P elements and I want each of them to have a different font family. 
I know I can accomplish this with CSS, but I prefer to experiment with Notepad++.

What I tried so far:
I selected the text in the P tag I want to change.
I went to: Settings > Style configurator > Language – HTML > Style – Singlestring > Font- webdings (for example).

This seems to change to UI font if I’m not mistaken. 
It doesn't change the text I selected in the P tag.

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to change the font of Notepad++ or the font of the webpage displayed in the browser.

Comment: I think you mixed something up. Notepad++ is no wysiwyg editor so you can't mark and set styles that get displays afterwards when your HTML is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to say that you want to change the fonts on your webpage in different divs I don't think it can be accomplished without CSS.

This is because notepad++ documents are only `.txt` and only store the raw text data.

If you're able to change the UI font on the webpage using notepad then I'm assuming it is actually changing CSS.

Don't be afraid to use CSS, it has awesome capabilities. CSS doesn't have to be in a different document external to your `index.html` it can be inline:

```
<div style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"> Enter Some Text </div>
```

If you want information on when to find and how to use different fonts try the [Google Fonts API](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto)